Google Maps Marker - How to find the right anchor for icon?
I changed the icon of an marker on google maps. When I do this, the marker is Moving, when I'm zooming.
I found out, that MarkerOptions.anchor() could help, so I tried it with diffenretn values. When I changed the values I recognized, that the marker is moving in other directions.
Here is my code:
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        map = googleMap
        val startpoint = LatLng(lat, lng)
        val option = MarkerOptions().position(startpoint).title(title).icon(bitMapFromVector(R.drawable.baseline_flag_24))
        map.addMarker(option)
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(startpoint, 15F))
    }

private fun bitMapFromVector(vectorResID:Int): BitmapDescriptor {
        val vectorDrawable =ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(),vectorResID)
        vectorDrawable!!.setBounds(0,0, vectorDrawable.intrinsicWidth,vectorDrawable.intrinsicHeight)
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.intrinsicWidth,vectorDrawable.intrinsicHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas)
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
    }

I changed the icon into the android asset baseline-flag:
Android baseline-flag
According to this documentation https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#anchor%28float,%20float%29
I thouht that
.anchor(0.0f, 1.0f)

would be the right anchor, but it isnt, the marker still moves.
Do you have an idea how I can stop this or how I can find the right anchor values?

would be easier with graphic you placed for marker. are you sure that anchor should be in very edge of this grafic, not e.g. .anchor(0.05f, 0.92f)?
